# Текст из файла в строку

Tags: c#

Программа должна считывать из текстового файла (.txt) весь текст и записывать его в массив строк по 100 символов. Файлы большого объема (от 10 Мбайт). Использую File.ReadAllText для загона всего текста в одну строку, а потом ее бью на части и загоняю в массив строк. Интерфейс программы сразу же "не отвечает". Можно это сделать как-то быстрее и проще? Или тогда лучше использовать async/await?

Comment: Вам нужно именно по 100 символов, не учитывая разбиение на строки?

Comment: И что делать с концами строк? Сохранять или удалять?

Comment: В этом и проблема, что ни один из символов не должен быть удален. Я убираю переносы строк для этого:
text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");

Comment: То есть концы строк всё же надо удалять?

Comment: И ещё раз, если строка короче 100 символов, то её нужно дополнить символами следующей строки, верно?

Comment: Если вы под концом строки понимаете перенос на новую строку, то концы удалять. Важно записать весь текст по 100 символов в массив строк без потери символов. Именно для этого я удаляю все переносы на новую строку, чтобы сначала записать текст в одну строку для дальнейшего разбития на подстроки.

Comment: Окей, напишу, когда доберусь до компьютера, если раньше никто не напишет.

Comment: Верно! Но я сейчас сделал по-другому: из всех строк сделал одну. Просто думаю, что можно сделать проще.

Answer (score 4):

Вот, отличное решение, через метод-расширение:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitChunk(this string s, int chunkSize)
    {
        int chunkCount = s.Length / chunkSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++)
            yield return s.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize);

        if (chunkSize * chunkCount < s.Length)
            yield return s.Substring(chunkSize * chunkCount);
    }
}



private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllStrings(int chunkSize, string filePath)
{
    using (var sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        var rawText = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        var text = rawText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
        return text.SplitChunk(chunkSize).ToList();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var listChunk = await GetAllStrings(100,"c:\\temp\\2.txt");
```

Comment: Я думаю, самая медленная часть — это получение `tempStr` (`Skip` должен по идее пробежать весь кусок строки по одному символу). Если заменить на `Substring`, должно быть существенно быстрее.

Comment: Я придумал отличное решение, по скорости не сильно уступает твоему (если уступает)

Comment: Ага, так должно быть существенно быстрее.

Comment: Я не замерял, но 10Мб файл сжирает почти мгновенно.

Comment: Как думаешь, старый код удалить или оставить как есть?

Comment: У меня 20 мегабайт читает 4.5 секунд. Имеет смысл новый код по крайней мере вынести в начало ответа.

Comment: Ага, в релиз-режиме 1.35, но `ReadAllLines` намного скорее, 0.21 сек.

Comment: Там еще сливать массив надо в одну строку.

Comment: Это я по поводу моего кода, я измерил только его.

Answer (score 4):

Ещё одно улучшение вдвое по скорости, за счёт увеличения буфера до 4К:

```
List<string> SplitByChars(int chunkSize, string path)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (var f = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        var buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder(chunkSize);
        int readCount;
        do
        {
            readCount = f.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < readCount; i++)
            {
                char c = buffer[i];
                if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
                    continue;
                currentLine.Append(c);
                if (currentLine.Length == chunkSize)
                {
                    result.Add(currentLine.ToString());
                    currentLine.Clear();
                }
            }
        } while (readCount > 0);
        if (currentLine.Length > 0)
            result.Add(currentLine.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Старый вариант:

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitByChars(int chunkSize, string path)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (var f = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        var buffer = new char[chunkSize];
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder(chunkSize);
        int readCount;
        do
        {
            var oldLength = currentLine.Length;
            var rest = chunkSize - currentLine.Length;
            readCount = f.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, rest);
            currentLine.Append(buffer, 0, rest);
            currentLine.Replace("\r", "", oldLength, rest);
            currentLine.Replace("\n", "", oldLength, currentLine.Length - oldLength);

            if ((readCount == 0 && currentLine.Length > 0) ||
                currentLine.Length == chunkSize)
            {
                result.Add(currentLine.ToString());
                currentLine.Clear();
            }
        } while (readCount > 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Я старался не грузить память чтением длинных строк, максимальное потребление памяти — один буфер размером в `chunkSize` и один `StringBuilder` с capacity в `chunkSize`.

Пользоваться так:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => SplitByChars(100, path));
```

Предыдущий вариант с `ReadBlockAsync` был примерно втрое медленнее.

---

Здесь слишком много работы «вручную», возможно, есть более изящное решение.

Comment: А не проще было `Task.Run` - внутрь засунуть?

Comment: @Сергей: Не очень хорошо, пусть лучше это сделается на клиентской стороне. Чтобы клиент мог, например, засунуть в `Task.Run` несколько операций вместе. Вот текст про это от Microsoft Parallel Framework team: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/